# Include Latex for Evernote

Tags: evernote, latex

The easiest way to include Latex-based math notation in Evernote is to generate an image from the Latex code using some tool like LaTeXiT and paste the image in Evernote. However, it cannot record the Latex code in place like by MathJax so that it can be modified later. Is there any way to include MathJax or similar function in Evernote, like in Wikipedia or Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind going third party [eaTags](https://eatags.com/feat.latex) does it.

[Marxi.co](https://marxi.co/) is another option.

Comment: I just tried it. It just not looks very good and does not support some syntax though. Thanks for letting me know  that.

Comment: Give marxi.co a shot. https://marxi.co/

Comment: Just tried Marxi.co. It looks good although I do not need most features beyond Latex support and it is not free. Thanks.

Comment: To save the digging required: marxi.co is free for 10 days, then $15.99/year: https://marxi.co/purchase.html